# My simple form activity does not run (Android)

Tags: android

This might be a basic question, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm trying to run a simple example code to create forms (Android 5.1.1. API 22) using a library called **NexusDialog** from [here](https://github.com/dkharrat/NexusDialog), but when I want to run it (given after referencing the required library code), I see the popular `FATAL EXCEPTION` error as shown bellow. How can I fix it?

```
07-16 14:24:07.959: E/AndroidRuntime(22469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 14:24:07.959: E/AndroidRuntime(22469): Process: com.example.test, PID: 22469
07-16 14:24:07.959: E/AndroidRuntime(22469): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.test.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.test-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

and here is the main code (exact project folder uploaded **[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70475776/Test.zip)**)

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import com.github.dkharrat.nexusdialog.FormActivity;
import com.github.dkharrat.nexusdialog.controllers.EditTextController;
import com.github.dkharrat.nexusdialog.controllers.FormSectionController;
import com.github.dkharrat.nexusdialog.controllers.SelectionController;

/**
 * Demonstrates the bare minimum to display a form in an Activity.
 */
public class MainActivity extends FormActivity {

    @Override protected void initForm() {
        setTitle("Simple Example");

        FormSectionController section = new FormSectionController(this, "Personal Info");
        section.addElement(new EditTextController(this, "firstName", "First name"));
        section.addElement(new EditTextController(this, "lastName", "Last name"));
        section.addElement(new SelectionController(this, "gender", "Gender", true, "Select", Arrays.asList("Male", "Female"), true));

        getFormController().addSection(section);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you worked on view?

Comment: Did you declare it as the main-activity in AndroidManifest.xml ? you should also override onCreate and `setContentView()` with your XML view file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your uploaded project
It's seem that you only add jar file, not the correct instruction in [NexusDialog](https://github.com/dkharrat/NexusDialog)
Because the Activity use some custom resource(which cannot be add by jar file), So you will need to follow the guide to add NexusDialog as a depedencies project.

Comment: Thanks. Works now! I didn't know .jar files are missing resources.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add your activity in AndroidManifest.xml. All your activities should be declared there. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, they are. Check my whole project for AndroidManifest.xml